# What is different between array variable address and simple variable address?

Tags: arrays, variables

I want to know mechanism of allocate address for simple variable and array elements variable.

for example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
     int a;
     int b;
     int x[2];
     cout<<&a<<endl<<&b<<endl;
     cout<<&x[0]<<endl<<&x[1]<<endl;
}
```

result for me is:

```
0113F788
0113F77C
0113F76C
0113F770
```

and if we sub two address of variable a and b(&a-&b) result is: C

and if we sub address of x[1] and x[0] result is: 4

what is the difference?

sorry for my bad English explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple.

For variables, the compiler allocates not consecutive values in the memory.

For arrays, the compiler allocates consecutive values in the memory. So in C++, you can access to the all array elements by pointer by increasing the memory location for the pointer by one!

Comment: Because in case of arrays, the memory is allocated contiguously. The int datatype takes 4 bytes in your case as I assume that you have a 64 bit compiler. So, the if the 0th element from the int array is at memory address 10. Then the 1st element will be at memory address 14, 2nd element will be at memory address 18 and so on. Hence you get the difference as 4.

Comment: I know array elements address allocation, but I don't understand difference 12(C) for allocation of address between two consecutive simple variable.